# Error "The getter 'userEmail' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, google-authentication

Trying to implement login using google with firebase. There are a lot of tutorials but this is the one I found the most understandable. Though I have some issues reading the value being passed.

I tried to debugPrint the value of the **email** from "**googleSignIn.dart**" and it shows the expected result.

But if I try to access it in the HomeScreen, the error "***The getter 'userEmail' was called on null***" shows.

This is my **googleSignIn.dart** file

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:proxigram/Screens/home.dart';
import 'package:proxigram/Screens/login.dart';
import '../Models/users.dart';
import '../Models/userProvider.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
  UserProvider userProvider = new UserProvider(user.providerId);


  if (!user.isAnonymous && user.getIdToken() != null) {
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();

    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    List<UserProvider> userData = new List<UserProvider>();
    userData.add(userProvider);


    UserDetails details = new UserDetails(
        user.providerId,
        user.displayName,
        user.photoUrl,
        user.email,
        userData,
);


    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen(userDetails: details)),
    );
  }
  return user;
}

void signOutGoogle() async {
  await googleSignIn.signOut();

  print("User Sign Out");
}
```

and this is how I get the data from my **homeScreen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import '../main.dart';
import '../Models/users.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final UserDetails userDetails;
  HomeScreen({Key key, @required this.userDetails}) : super(key: key); 


  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  UserDetails userDetails;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(userDetails.userEmail),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Improve your question and post whole code.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I posted the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `widget.userDetails.userEmail` as it is passed by the `StatefulWidget` builder.

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(widget.userDetails.userEmail),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Remembering that you have to initialize obj

```
final UserDetails userDetails;
```

like this

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import '../main.dart';
import '../Models/users.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final UserDetails userDetails;
  HomeScreen({Key key, @required this.userDetails}) : super(key: key); 


  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState(this.userDetails);
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(widget.userDetails.userEmail),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object is null because you didn't populate it. You must pass as parameter to your state and use a constructor to populate your object.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import '../main.dart';
import '../Models/users.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final UserDetails userDetails;
  HomeScreen({Key key, @required this.userDetails}) : super(key: key); 


  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState(this.userDetails);
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  UserDetails userDetails;

  _HomeScreenState(UserDetais userDetails) {
      this.userDetails = userDetails;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(userDetails.userEmail),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```